# Sandcastle and Crystal Reports Visual Studio 2008 to 2010

Tags: crystal-reports, sandcastle

We use Crystal Reports with Visual Studio.  We are using Sandcastle to build documentation.  Seems like everything worked fine when we were on Visual Studio 2008.  Now that we're using Visual Studio 2010, I get a Crystal Reports related error when trying to build the documentation.

> MREFBUILDER : error : Unresolved assembly reference: BusinessObjects.Licensing.KeycodeDecoder (BusinessObjects.Licensing.KeycodeDecoder, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304) required by CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
>       Last step completed in 00:00:03.3283

Browsing the web shows that there were some people with a similar problem, but none of them seem to have gotten it fixed.  Does anyone know what could be causing this error?

Thanks ahead of time for the help!

Answer (score 2):

There is now a permanent fix in the latest Sandcastle to process Dot Net projects that include Crystal Reports - please see the post http://geekswithblogs.net/TATWORTH/archive/2012/10/12/sandcastle-help-file-builder---october-2010-release.aspx

The latest Sandcastle download is at http://shfb.codeplex.com/releases/view/92191